# POP3_SSL Not Found in poplib module

Tags: python, ssl, pop3

What would cause this strange error when trying to use the poplib.POP3_SSL class.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 131, in <module>
    M = poplib.POP3_SSL('XXXXXXXX', 995)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'POP3_SSL'
```

My environment is Python 2.6, REHL5

I've never run into this problem before and it just so happens to be a problem with only one of my servers in rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your python might be compiled without ssl support.

Comment: Do you know of a way to determine if it is or not?

EDIT: You are right, no SSL classes or modules work on this one server. Thanks.